# como puedo conectar un formulario a la base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql

les dejo mi código de formulario y conexión.. les agradeceria mucho su ayuda

index.html



    formulario de contacto

```
 <div class="form">
    <form action="guardar.php" method="POST">

         <p>nombre</p>
         <label for="nombre">su nombre</label>
         <br>
         <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>

         <p>correo</p>
         <label for="correo">direccion de correo</label>
         <br>
         <input type="email" name="correo" placeholder="alguien@gmail.com" required>

         <p>mensaje</p>
         <label for="mensaje">su mensaje</label>
         <br>
         <textarea name="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje" required></textarea>
         <br>
         <br>
         <input type="submit" value="Enviar">

    </form>
 </div>
```

estilo.css

```
.form{
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 600px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    background-color: #e5dfcd;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: auto;
}

input[type=text],[type=email]{
    width: 470px;
    height: 35px;
    font: 14px normal normal uppercase helvetica, arial, serif;
}

textarea{
    width: 470px;
    height: 110px;
    font: 14px normal normal uppercase helvetica, arial, serif;
}

input[type=submit]{
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: #32A43E;
    font: 14px normal normal uppercase helvetica, arial, serif;
}

p{
    text-shadow: 0 1px o #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
}

label{
    margin: 11px 20px 0 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #b3aba1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
}
```

guardar.php

```
<? php

$conectar = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','', 'prueba');

    if(!$conectar){
        echo "No conectado";
    }

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $correo = $_POST['correo'];
    $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO datos(nombre, correo, mensaje) VALUES ('$nombre', '$correo', '$mensaje')";

    $ejecutar = mysqli_query($conectar, $sql);

    if(!$ejecutar){
        echo "Hay algun error";
    }else{
        echo "Datos almacenados correctamente";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Bienvenida Daniela, tu pregunta es un poco amplia con el contenido de la respuesta y por tu misma pregunta a l que le falta aclarar algunas cosas, hay distintos modos de conexión a una BD y a su ves, también dependiendo de que tipo de BD, los modos van a ir cambiando. No es recomendable que supongamos algunas cosas de tu código, sería bueno que para que te podamos responder con exactitud, nos  des más info, mientras tanto puedes darte una vuelta por [ask] para más información

Answer (score 1):

Añado un poco de PHP a tu código, espero que sea lo que necesitas. Recuerda crear en tu servidor MySQL la base de datos stackoverflow.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['correo'])){
        $conn=new mysqli('localhost','root','','stackoverflow');
        $conn->query("
            CREATE TABLE if NOT EXISTS contactos(
              id_contacto int AUTO_INCREMENT,
              nombre varchar(127),
              correo varchar(127),
              mensaje text,
              PRIMARY KEY(id_contacto)
              );        
        ");
        if($conn->query("
            INSERT INTO contactos (nombre, correo, mensaje) VALUES (
                '".$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['nombre'])."',
                '".$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['correo'])."',
                '".$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['mensaje'])."'
            );      
        ")) echo 'Mensaje correctamente registrado';
        else echo 'Hemos tenido dificultades registrando tu mensaje, por favor reinténtalo';
    }
?>

 <div class="form">
    <form method="POST">

         <p>nombre</p>
         <label for="nombre">su nombre</label>
         <br>
         <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>

         <p>correo</p>
         <label for="correo">direccion de correo</label>
         <br>
         <input type="email" name="correo" placeholder="alguien@gmail.com" required>

         <p>mensaje</p>
         <label for="mensaje">su mensaje</label>
         <br>
         <textarea name="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje" required></textarea>
         <br>
         <br>
         <input type="submit" value="Enviar">

    </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: Ok, acabo de verlo. Modifico guardar.php en un momentito. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Únicamente tienes que corregir guardar.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['correo'])){
        $conn=new mysqli('localhost','root','','prueba');
        $conn->query("
            CREATE TABLE if NOT EXISTS contactos(
              id_contacto int AUTO_INCREMENT,
              nombre varchar(127),
              correo varchar(127),
              mensaje text,
              PRIMARY KEY(id_contacto)
              );        
        ");
        if($conn->query("
            INSERT INTO contactos (nombre, correo, mensaje) VALUES (
                '".$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['nombre'])."',
                '".$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['correo'])."',
                '".$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['mensaje'])."'
            );      
        ")) echo 'Mensaje correctamente registrado';
        else echo 'Hemos tenido dificultades registrando tu mensaje, por favor reinténtalo';
    }
?>
```